# Is there a way to search using regular expressions?

Tags: google-search, regex

It would be very useful if Google provided a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) search.

Is there a way to do this?

I am not talking about search operators like `site:`, `filetype:`,  `AND`, `OR` or `"Text"`. I would like to search with a regular expression like `.+[]^`).

For example, is there an application, a site or a Google tool to search things like `*.stackexchange`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This feature is not available in classic Google Search and it's not in Google's roadmap. You can learn more about this topic watching the Google video [Will Google implement the ability to search with regular expressions?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYiTIDgejas)

However, there was one exception. [Google Code Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code_Search) (`http://www.google.com/codesearch`) supported regular expressions. Of course, the search target for this topic search engine was reduced to source code only.

It is worth mentioning that some Google search keywords can partially replace regular expressions. For example, if you want to search any two-word variation of "search TERM", you can use the wildcard operator.

```
search *
```

will find results for search and any other (one) word. I often use it to check basic English grammar rules or synonyms (e.g., ["as easy as *"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22as%20easy%20as%20*%22)).

Comment: [Google Code Search no longer exists](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/fall-sweep.html), but [there may be alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778034/replacement-for-google-code-search) (not that it's relevant to this question)

Comment: This answer is obsolete because Google Code Search no longer exists, `*` is no longer a search operator.  More details in my answer to [Where to find a list of Google search operators?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122235/88163)

Answer (score 13):

Google Search can return the matches of patterns that resemble regular expressions.
For example, the search query

```
"(gray|red) (wolf|fox)"
```

appears to be equivalent to

```
("gray wolf" OR "red fox" OR "red wolf" OR "gray fox")
```

You can see the output of this search query [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%28red%7Cgray%29+%28wolf%7Cfox%29%22).

Google Search also allows "wildcard" characters in search strings, so you can find search results for patterns like [`"the quick brown * (jumped|jumps) over the * dog"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+quick+brown+*+(jumped%7Cjumps)+over+the+*+dog%22).

Comment: The claim that a query using Google Search OR operator is using a regular expression is misleading.

Comment: @Rubén The search operators don't support most of the features of regular expressions, but I thought this particular example ( [`(gray|red) (wolf|fox)`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%28red%7Cgray%29+%28wolf%7Cfox%29%22) ) worked like a regular expression. Does this search query not only show results that include matches of that regular expression?

Comment: Nowadays `*` and `|` aren't search operators.  More details in my answer to [Where to find a list of Google search operators?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122235/88163)

Answer (score 8):

You can write a piece of software to:

1. Take the keywords from the regular expression;
2. Google the keywords and get a list of results;
3. Crawl each resulting URI and filter it with complete regular expression.

Let's study a case: from `site:gog.com` find all games that have Spanish voice-over.

The regular expression is:

```
Audio[^:]*:[^.,]*Spanish
```

It shall match, for example:

```
Audio lanuage: English, German, Spanish, French.
```

And not match:

```
Audio language: only-English. Text language: Spanish.
```

Step 1. Let your software search this on Google:

```
site:gog.com audio Spanish inurl:game
```

`inurl:game` here means only search in game description pages

Step 2. Get the 300 resulting links and crawl into every one of them.

Step 3. Filter the result with the given regular expression:

```
Audio[^:]*:[^.,]*Spanish
```

This should be easy to build. In fact I don't understand why I couldn't find something that is already built that way.

Since search engines can't afford the resource to scan their data with regular expression, this dirty job falls on your part, and your computer should do that with what search engines already provide.

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately not :(. In theory you could make your own search engine and do it, but that would be pretty hard.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, Google's help on search operators is [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433).

Interestingly, "-" is still an operator for word exclusion, but they removed "+" as an operator, used in the past to require a given search term. Apparently, "The + operator was retired when Google+ was launched, because + was needed as a searchable character rather than an operator."(https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433)

Comment: The linked help article is still being referred to as the most current documentation for end-users but it looks more as comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> However, there's one exception. Google Code Search supports regular
> expressions. Of course, the search target for this topic search engine
> is reduced to source code only.

There are actually two exceptions:  You can run Google Script type regex searches in Google Drive.  Example:  `/\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}/`

Maybe someday they'll carry that over to web search.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, and the second part doesn't answer the question. By Google, the OP is referring to the Web Search, not to the company.

Answer (score -4):

If you know VBA, you can write some code to get data from the web to Excel. I run the program day and night and can get millions of results. After that you can filter from those results.

Comment: The core of this idea is not limited to VBA. It might be done using almost any programming language. You should have included more details to make it clear what might be the advantages if you were thinking of automating Internet Explorer, probably this answer is obsolete nowadays.