# Find number in Google with wildcards

Tags: google-search

I want to find a number that starts with "221" and is an 11 digit number.

For example: **221XXXXXXXX**

Does Google support any method to find something like this? Perhaps with regex or wildcards?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the regex question, as having an incidental answer to an unasked question elsewhere is not the same as a direct answer to a direct question.

Comment: This is not duplicate question.

Comment: I've tried to modify the question to make it clear it's not a duplicate.

Comment: The "regex" question referred to above is http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/is-there-a-way-to-search-in-google-using-regular-expressions-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be possible. As far as I can tell, this capability has been removed. I suspect that they were uncomfortable with how easy it was to find lists of credit card numbers, phone numbers, and social security numbers using this function.