# Google Search exact string problem

Tags: google-search

I've tried to find an *exact* string using Google Search. The string looks like this: `xx-xxxx` where the "x" can be any number or letter. After the first two characters there is a dash and after this 4 other characters, like this: `1A-59B4`. Is there a way to search only the exact structure using Google Search? I tried `**-****` but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you specifically searching for the phrase "1A-59B4" or trying to find anything that has that format? If it's the latter, you need to be searching using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info) - which Google does not currently support.

Comment: [Is there a way to search in Google using Regular Expressions (regex)?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19673)

Answer (score -2):

I guess you should try this way: "[EXACT_STRING]" without any signs near ". I mean don't put - near " like here "-**"

Comment: Using quotes in a Google search enables the exact-string search. If it's within the quotes the exact symbol is searched for as part of the string. The "-" only negates the character if it is outside of quotes or parenthesis.