# Why doesn't Google give search results for '*' [asterisk]?

Tags: google-search, regex, special-characters

You can search for anything on Google, right? At least, so I thought. I was trying to see how the special characters get encoded in the url, like how `&` gets converted to `%26`. I started searching for `*`. It did not get encoded, but weirdly google didn't tell me that it was an asterisk symbol. All other search engines (yahoo, bing, duckduckgo) did.

See for yourself : [In Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=*). Basically it treats it as a regular expression. So `*+*` will also not give any results. Still, shouldn't Google at least say that `*` is the asterisk symbol.

I don't know where else to ask this question, so I came to SO.

Comment: Perhaps this link might provide some useful information? http://booleanblackbelt.com/2009/09/google-search-the-asterisk-wildcard-and-punctuation/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete. The link pointing to a Google Search query, no longer returns the same results than when the question was created.

Answer (score 3):

Google Search doesn't allow searching for punctuation characters.

Further, the asterisk (`*`) acts as a wildcard character in searches. For instance

```
* tart recipe
```

Should return recipes for apple tarts, pear tarts, cherry tarts, etc.

Google's own example from the [search operators support page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) is

```
a * saved is a * earned
```

([That page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) also lists other special characters that can be used in search which, obviously, are then impossible to search for.)

Here's some other information you might find useful:

- [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23/354)
- [How to search the internet for terms with special characters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1479/354)
- [Is there a way to search in Google using regular expressions (regex)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19673/354)

Comment: Yes I understand that Google search with regex is what we are discussing and so *  is simply a wildcard. Still I repeat my question: when you search for * in Google, why isn't Google saying that it is an asterisk symbol? Shouldn't that be the default behaviour of any search engine?

Comment: Generally speaking, the only people who can answer _why_ Google do anything is Google, and they're not active here.

Comment: This answer is obsolete.