# Is there a way to search the web by using regex?

Tags: search-engine, regex

I want to study and find English sentence examples. For example, I read some `I'd be working...` I want to know the usage of `I'd be doing...` So I want to search

```
I'd be *ing
```

I'd like to see the sentences of "I'd be eating... I'd be running..."

If there is a way to search with a regex in novel or news websites, that would be pretty effective.

Is there a search engine that does this?

[google doesn't support regex search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/is-there-a-way-to-search-in-google-using-regular-expressions-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/

search:

```
I 'd be *ing
```

Please notice, there should be a space between `I` and `'d`.

Comment: The OP wants to search the web. I admit that was not very clear from the question, but it would be off-topic otherwise.